# Choosing file from drive using file chooser

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, filechooser

In an ionic app,

Using `@ionic-native/filechooser` I’m selecting drive document.
I will get the url as

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DOWWfReHHsomYzNVkcRQjdDz2I_xVdBwrW5n6x_6_fOd30Vh7%0A
```

In this will not get the type of File.?

How to get the type of file selected?

Answer (score 0):

`import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';`

[plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

After getting the file path use above plugin to get file details.

I didn't tried it myself , you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
selectFile(){
    var filter = { "mime": "application/pdf" }  // text/plain, image/png, image/jpeg, audio/wav etc
    this.fileChooser.open(filter, function(response){
      //success
      console.log("success"+reponse); 
    }, function(error){
      console.log("error"+error)
    })

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**File Chooser**

**install this plugin**

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filechooser
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-chooser
```

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  img:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private fileChooser: FileChooser) {

  }
  openFile(){
    this.fileChooser.open()
    .then((sucess)=>{
      console.log(sucess + 'successfull');
      this.img = sucess;
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err + 'Try again')
    })
  }

}
```

It will open your phone file manager and you can choose any file which you want.

```
.then((sucess)=>{
      console.log(sucess + 'successfull');
      this.img = sucess;
    })
```

This part help you to know the selected file type.